# Convert from hex to int and vice versa in java

Tags: java, hex

I have next method for converting to int from hex:

```
public static byte[] convertsHexStringToByteArray2(String hexString) {
    int hexLength = hexString.length() / 2;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hexLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < hexLength; i++) {
        int hex = Integer.parseInt(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16);
        bytes[i] = (byte) hex;
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

when I use it for "80" hex string I get strange, not expected result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(convertsHexStringToByteArray2("80"))); // gives -128
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(-128));
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(128));
}
```

the output:

```
[-128]
ffffff80
80
```

I expect that "80" will be 128. What is wrong with my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have next method for converting **to int from hex**

The method you posted converts a hex String to a byte array, and not to an `int`. That's why it is messing with its sign.

Converting **from hex to int** is easy:

```
Integer.parseInt("80", 16)
$1 ==> 128
```

But if you want to get a byte array for further processing by just casting:

```
(byte) Integer.parseInt("80", 16)
$2 ==> -128
```

It "changes" its sign. For further information on primitives and signed variable types take a look at [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), where it says:

> The *byte data type* is an **8-bit signed** two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of **-128** and a maximum value of **127 (inclusive)**. The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

One could easily invert the sign by just increasing the value to convert:

```
(byte) Integer.parseInt("80", 16) & 0xFF
$3 ==> 128
```

That gets you a byte with the value you expect. Technically that result isn't correct and you must to switch the sign again, if you want to get an int or a hex string back again. I'd suggest you to don't use a byte array if you only want to convert between hex and dec.

Comment: Thanks. I messed. That's a byte type

Answer (score 0):

A byte in Java stores numbers from -128 to 127. 80 in hex is 128 as an integer, which is too large to be stored in a byte. So, the value wraps around. Use a different type to store your value (such as a short).